# Invoking android apk from another apk

Tags: android, process, invoke, apk

I tried invoking an android apk (AA1) from another apk (BB1) by raising intent. But BB1 starts starts AA1 in its own process space and it does not use the existing running process of AA1. How can I achieve
a. I want BB1 to use existing AA1 if it is already running. 
b. If it is not already there, it should invoke AA1 as an independent application.

Answer (score 0):

> a. I want BB1 to use existing AA1 if it is already running

You can try having BB1 use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as flags on the `Intent` used to start the activity from AA1, though I have only tried this for a single app, not between two apps.

> b. If it is not already there, it should invoke AA1 as an independent application.

This will happen by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think by setting same process ID in Manifest.xml will work.